# How can I catch RedisConnectionFailureException on spring boot and let my application run until Redis is ready again?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to catch RedisConnectionFailureException. The reason for that is that I need the other parts of the application running. I am expected to try connect to redis periodically until successful. How can I tell spring boot that I just need to see that app is not ready in actuator/health/readinessState but I still need other functionality of the app. Right now when I start up the application and the redis module is down, my app crashes. It also crashes when redis breaks when app is running. What would be correct way of doing this in spring boot